# how in rxjs bubble a scroll event

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

with vanilla js, I can write something like this to catch any scroll on any element (pay attention to **true** as the last argument)

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
   console.log(e);
}, true);
```

but with rxjs I can't do the bubbling (or I don't know how) and something like this doesn't work

```
fromEvent(window, 'scroll').subscribe(console.log);
```

how to register an event in rxjs that support bubbling?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass options to [`fromEvent`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/fromEvent) (see Examples) as well:

```
fromEvent(window, 'scroll', { capture: true }).subscribe(console.log);

// or

fromEvent(window, 'scroll', true).subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: thanks, do you also know how to achieve the same in angular @hostListener?

Comment: thats another question i guess :)

Comment: The first one @martin gives as an example works for Angular just in case anyone was wondering :)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case it might be helpful for someone.
To target scroll of specific element:

```
const el = document.getElementById('element-id-with-scroll') as HTMLElement;

fromEvent(el, 'scroll')
  .pipe(
    debounceTime(300)
  )
 .subscribe(res => console.log(res))
```